# mxGraph : When I remove all cells the layout manager stops working

Tags: mxgraph

My goal, draw a graph and then draw a new graph based on new input data
My solution so far, create a graph, add vertices and edges
and when I press clean I will do the following :

```
graph.removeCells(graph.getChildVertices(graph.getDefaultParent()));
graph.getModel().clear();
```

And then start adding new vertices and edges
but now the layout manager stops working

Comment: You would like to implement a function that deletes all cells and edges on call correctly?

Comment: correct, I am drawing a brand new diagram, but the layout manager stops working

Comment: The call from `graph.removeCells(graph.getChildVertices(graph.getDefaultParent()));` is sufficient to remove all cells on the graph.  You don´t have to call `graph.getModel().clear();` afterwards. You only need to call `graph.getModel().beginUpdate();` and `graph.getModel().endUpdate();` when inserting and updating cells.